# OpenShift EGIT Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, git, openshift

Has anyone out there actually gotten an existing Eclipse Dynamic Web Project working under OpenShift?  Does anyone know a tutorial that ties all three title elements together?

I have the OpenShift plug-in and the EGIT plug-in added to Eclipse Kepler.

I've tried creating a new OpenShift Project in Eclipse.  It does well until the final step when it errors for wanting the location an ssh "pub" file.  Nothing prior had mentioned this and even if I knew where it was or what they were talking about, there's no place in any of the dialogs to enter it.

I've started any number of GIT and OpenShift tutorials or guidelines.  Most think that everyone is using Red Hat Linux.  I'm using Windows 8.

It doesn't appear that OpenShift will let you select an existing Eclipse Dynamic Web Project that doesn't already somehow magically exist in OpenShift.

I've read the solutions to other user's problems as supplied by Red Hat and they're all very fragmentary and tend to stipulate a degree of knowledge that the questioner simply doesn't have.

It's all been very confusing.  I want to host my Dynamic Web Project on OpenShift because they support Tomcat 7, JDK 7 and MySQL 5.5, but somehow I've not found the magic bullet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use newer version of `JBT (or OpenShift tools)` - there are more and more changes over time (new features, fixes...). Newer `JBT` cannot allow you to start create a new application without having your public key on your `OpenShift account`.

According to your issue. You have to have uploaded your public `ssh key` on the `OpenShift` to successfully deploy your existing application. It's required, `bcs`. there is at first created OpenShift application with specific cartridge (in your case Tomcat 7) and then it is overwritten by local application (forced push) - and there is required ssh key for secured connection. That is a reason why you cannot deploy your existing application.

To upload `SSH key` to your `OpenShift accoun`t open OpenShift explorer and choose your connection, open its context menu and choose Manage SSH Keys... (older version could have different label for this, but it would not be much more different). `If you don't have any ssh key, wizard allow you to create your own key pair`. Make sure, that SSH key is also added into Eclipse SSH2 preferences (I am not sure, which version of OpenShift tools do you use, if there is not link to eclipse preferences, go through `Preferences -> General -> Network Connection -> SSH2`).